# How to append the value in table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am doing one date range form field,here **console.log(fname)** means i got all values and i want to append this value in one table **td**,i am trying like this method,but it is not working,how can i append this value in **td**

```html
     <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="reservation">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#reservation").on("change", function() {
            var reservation = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'date-range.php',
                data: {
                    logindate: reservation,
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    var res = jQuery.parseJSON(data); // convert the json
                    console.log(res);
                    if (res['status'] == "success") {

                        var htmlString = '';

                        $.each(res['data'], function(key, value) {

                            htmlString += '<tr>';
                            var ssm_id = value.ssm_id; // here i got ssmid
                            htmlString += '<td>' + value.ssm_id + '</td>';
                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'post',
                                url: 'config/functions.php',
                                data: {
                                    ssm_id: ssm_id,
                                },
                                success: function(fname) {
                                    console.log(fname); //here i got all names
                                    // kani
                                    // mahi
                                    // kogila like this ans it will come console.log(fname),i want appent this value in hmlString+='<td>'+fname+'</td>';
                                    htmlString += '<td>' + fname + '</td>'; // here value is not appending,nothing is happen
                                }
                            });

                            htmlString += '<td>' + 'Muthuraja' + '</td>';
                            htmlString += '<td>' + '20-05-2016' + '</td>';
                            htmlString += '<td>' + 'status' + '</td>';
                            htmlString += '<td>' + value.source + '</td>';
                            htmlString += '<td>' + "<span style='color:green'>View Profile</span>" + '</td>';

                            htmlString += '</tr>';
                        });
                        $('#datatable-editable > tbody').empty().append(htmlString);
                    } else {
                        $('#datatable-editable > tbody').empty().append("<center style='height:100px;padding-top:36px;color:red;font-size:17px;'><b>No matching records found</b></center>");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>


functions.php

<?php
    $ssm_id = $_POST['ssm_id'];
    if(!empty($ssm_id)){
    echo firstname($ssm_id);
    }

    function firstname($id)
     {
      $f="SELECT firstname FROM register WHERE matri_id='$id'";
      $rr=mysql_query($f);
      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rr))
       {
        $firstname = $row['firstname'];
       }
       return $firstname;
     }

    ?>
```

Comment: Your `ajax` inside `success` operation of first `ajax` will not work properly as you are continuing with your work of appending values to `htmlString` without waiting for completion of `ajax` inside `success`

Comment: How can do this????possible means update ur answer

Comment: Why don't you use join instead of making two ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just writing the `success` part. Hope you will get this to working structure.

```
success: function(data) {
  var res = jQuery.parseJSON(data); // convert the json
  console.log(res);
  if (res['status'] == "success") {
    $('#datatable-editable > tbody').empty();//emtpy tbody at the begining
    $.each(res['data'], function(key, value) {
      var htmlString = ''; //Place declaration inside each
      htmlString += '<tr>';
      var ssm_id = value.ssm_id; // here i got ssmid
      htmlString += '<td>' + value.ssm_id + '</td>';
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'config/functions.php',
        data: {
          ssm_id: ssm_id,
        },
        success: function(fname) {
          htmlString += '<td>' + fname + '</td>'; 
          //move the whole set inside success of this ajax
          htmlString += '<td>' + 'Muthuraja' + '</td>';
          htmlString += '<td>' + '20-05-2016' + '</td>';
          htmlString += '<td>' + 'status' + '</td>';
          htmlString += '<td>' + value.source + '</td>';
          htmlString += '<td>' + "<span style='color:green'>View Profile</span>" + '</td>';
          htmlString += '</tr>';
          $('#datatable-editable > tbody').append(htmlString);
        }
      });

    });

  }
}
```

Comment: I have one more doubt,how to call the one more function in this code.isteed of this   htmlString += '<td>' + 'Muthuraja' + '</td>';  i want to call the function <?php echo castename($ssm_id);?>,how can do here

Comment: Add one more `ajax` add move the rest of the things inside.. But this will be more complicated... So its better to simplify and try to make one ajax request. You have to design your server side code like that..

Comment: I tried to add one more ajax but it is not working properly,possible means update your answer Mr  @@ Guruprasad

Comment: If u update answer means it will helpfull for me,actually i am fresher thats y i am struglling Mr Guruprasad

Comment: There isn't much information on you question dear, also the php thing, I have very less idea with that framework. It will be good if you post it as separate question with proper details, like server side code, client side code etc.,